# Python: how string with list works together? 'spam'[1:3] how this works?

Tags: python, string, slice

I searched already before on this question on 
how this statement is valid in python?

```
>>> 'spam'[1:3]
>>> 'pa'
```

Question is how slicing is associated with str type. Is it plain concatenation with 'spam'.

Thanks
--Div

Comment: This not a string and and a list, it's a string with a slice notation, saying take the part of the string `'spam'` that starts from index `1` and ends before index `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `str` type can be sliced is because they have `__getslice__` method (in python 2) and `__getitem__` method (in both python 2 and 3).

`dir('spam')` will show you these methods.

Also, try `'spam'.__getslice__(1,3)` in python 2 or `'spam'.__getitem__(slice(1,3))` in python 3.

You can refer to [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**getslice**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__) for more details.

Comment: perfect, Thanks for info.

Answer (score 2):

Slicing creates a copy of an object

One way to remember how slices work is to think of the indices as pointing between characters, with the left edge of the first character numbered 0. Then the right edge of the last character of a string of n characters has index n, for example:

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | P | y | t | h | o | n |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
-6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

The first row of numbers gives the position of the indices 0…6 in the string; the second row gives the corresponding negative indices. The slice from i to j consists of all characters between the edges labeled i and j, respectively.

In your case

```
 +---+---+---+---+
 | s | p | a | m |
 +---+---+---+---+
 0   1   2   3   4
-4  -3  -2  -1  

>>> 'spam'[1:3]
'pa'
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of strings like ordinary arrays if this helps. For example

```
0 1 2 3 
s p a m
```

so `spam[1:3]` gives the contents of positions `[1, 3)` of the string, that is `pa`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply consider a string like an immutable list of characters (which are themselves strings of length 1) :

```
>>> list('spam')
['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']
>>> sorted('spam')
['a', 'm', 'p', 's']
>>> [c * 2 for c in 'spam']
['ss', 'pp', 'aa', 'mm']
```

It means that assignment doesn't work, but slicing is just the same as for a list:

```
>>> 'spam'[1:3]
'pa'
>>> list('spam')[1:3]
['p', 'a']
```